# Why are some git commands has single - for additional options whereas some others have --

Tags: git

I am trying to learn the git commands and it is confusing that some commands in git uses single single **-**

```
git log -n 2
```

Whereas some other commands use **--**

```
git log --grep
```

I think there should be a particular pattern in which we use single hypen and double hypen with git commands. Could someone please explain this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name of an option is long such as the full word `grep` use `--`, Otherwise for single character options like `n` use `-`.

Note that `-grep` is the same as the four short options `-g -r -e -p`. `tar` does this but notably `find` does not which is why `find` does not need `--` for long options.

Long options were an extension. There used to only be short options but there are only 62.